# if statement get rid of: Error in if: argument is of length zero

Tags: r, shiny

**The idea**

Depending on `selectizeInput()` input I want to display one row of data from a data frame. However, some variables are only to be displayed if their value is not `FALSE`. `selectizeInput()` includes a placeholder prompt, which is highly desirable.

**The problem**

The code I developed actually works but until any option is selected displays

> Error in if: argument is of length zero

inside the app, which is highly undesirable.

**Example code**

```
library("shiny")

# simulate data
data <- data.frame(
  name = c("Adam", "Debbie", "Lancelot", "Dracula"),
  age = c(21, 48, 72, 1023),
  coward = c("yes, a coward", "just a little bit", FALSE, "too old to be a coward")
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  # selectize
  selectizeInput(
    inputId = "input",
    label = NULL,
    choices = c("..." = "", as.character(data[, "name"])),
    selected = NULL,
    multiple = FALSE
  ),
  # show output
  uiOutput(outputId = "output")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$output <- renderUI({
    div(
      # show name
      data[which(input$input == data[, "name"]), "name"], br(),
      data[which(input$input == data[, "name"]), "age"], br(),
      # if "coward" is not FALSE than show its value
      if(data[which(input$input == data[, "name"]), "coward"] != FALSE){
        data[which(input$input == data[, "name"]), "coward"]
      }
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Attempted solutions**

Tried wrapping `if()` statement in `suppressWarnings()` or `suppressMessages()`. Does not change anything. Also tried putting `!is.null(input$input) &&` inside `if()` condition but it just changes the initial error to

> Error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

**The question**

How to write the condition so that `shiny` would not return an error before selecting an option in `selectizeInput()`?

Any other, more general hack to force `shiny` not to display error messages inside the app?

I feel I`m missing something obvious here...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer including `browser()` function was indeed helpful for locating the source of the problem but the real solution is to use `req()` or a combination of `validate()` and `need()` functions. See respective `help()` pages to learn how to use them.

In short what these functions do is to check whether the argument given has been specified. In reference to the example code the solution could look like this:

```
server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$output <- renderUI({
    # check if input$input is specified
    # if not stop executing the rest of this code block
    req(input$input)
    div(
      # show name
      data[which(input$input == data[, "name"]), "name"], br(),
      data[which(input$input == data[, "name"]), "age"], br(),
      # if "coward" is not FALSE than show its value
      if(data[which(input$input == data[, "name"]), "coward"] != FALSE){
        data[which(input$input == data[, "name"]), "coward"]
      }
    )
  })
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Whenever you get an error you're not sure about in R, the first thing to do is to try to isolate it and use `browser()` to see what happens just before the error. After doing this, I found out the error has nothing to do with shiny or the UI, it's just because you're trying to compare a `factor(0)` to `FALSE`.

The value of `input$input` is initially `""`. This means the value of `data[which(input$input == data[, "name"]), "coward"]` is initially `factor(0)`. Which means your if statement is doing a `factor(0) == FALSE` comparison, which breaks.

To figure that out all I needed to do was simplify the server code to

```
server <- function(input, output, session){
  observe({
    mydata <- data[which(input$input == data[, "name"]), "coward"]
    browser()
    if (mydata == FALSE) {
      cat("hello")
    }
  })
}
```

And using the debugger I saw what values are being used

Comment: Your answer prooved helpful. After a discussion with a colleague I managed to find a workaround of the problem. See my answer if you are interested.

Comment: Haven't looked at your answer, but I don't think you need to "find a workaround". This is a very common issue in shiny and the simple proper solution is to simple use the `req()` function or check for proper input before handling it

Answer (score 0):

A hack that works:

```
server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$output <- renderUI({
    div(
      # show name
      data[which(input$input == data[, "name"]), "name"], br(),
      data[which(input$input == data[, "name"]), "age"], br(),
      # if "coward" is not FALSE than show its value
      if((length(input$input) > 1) && 
         (data[which(input$input == data[, "name"]), "coward"] != FALSE)){
        data[which(input$input == data[, "name"]), "coward"]
      }
    )
  })
}
```

Comment: It is true that no error is shown but also the app doesn`t show the variable "coward" even if specified.