# Html output to display the the description of each function

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to build a r shiny app where the user will get to know about each function in just a click. For this I have coded below in R . But `print(??input$A)` is not working. Could anyone help please

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(readxl)
out <- data.frame(baseFns = ls('package:base'))
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Loading data"),
  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Analysis", tabName = "Analysis", icon = icon("chart-bar"))
  )),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(tabItem(tabName = "Analysis",
                     fluidRow(box(selectInput("A","A",choices = c(levels(factor(out$baseFns))),width = "150px"),width = 2),
                              fluidRow(box(htmlOutput("Text"),width = 9)))
             )
    ))
)

server <- function(input,output){
  output$Text <- renderText({
    print(??input$A)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Something like this on the `server` will work `output$Text <- renderUI({
        print(help.search(input$A))`. `help.search` is the equivalent of `??`. On top of that you might also need to implement an on click event.

Comment: Thanks, But it is not working. I got error ````argument is not a character vector````

Comment: Can't reproduce your error. What I see is `Warning: Error in if: argument is of length zero`, which you can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39519491/if-statement-get-rid-of-error-in-if-argument-is-of-length-zero) to handle.

Comment: Not sure why you are getting that error. I just replaced your code to mine :) Not sure why

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(gbRd) # for Rd_fun
library(tools) # for Rd2HTML

out <- data.frame(baseFns = ls('package:base'))

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Loading data"),
  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Analysis", tabName = "Analysis", icon = icon("chart-bar"))
  )),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "Analysis",
        fluidRow(
          box(selectInput("A", "Topic", choices = levels(factor(out$baseFns)), 
                          width = "150px"), 
              width = 2),
          fluidRow(box(htmlOutput("helpfun"), width = 9))
        )
      )
    ))
)

server <- function(input, output, session){

  output$helpfun <- renderUI({
    Rd <- Rd_fun(help(input$A)) 
    outfile <- tempfile(fileext = ".html")
    Rd2HTML(Rd, outfile, package = "",
            stages = c("install", "render"))
    includeHTML(outfile)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks, Can you please explain the code from ````output$helpfun <- renderUI({````

Comment: @DevP `Rd_fun` produces a Rd object (see `?Rd_fun`). Then you can pass it to `Rd2HTML` to generate a HTML file. I don't know what is the `stages` argument, I copied from `?Rd2HTML`. Finally you include the HTML file with the shiny function `includeHTML`.

Comment: Hi @stephane. Could you help me in this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59232900/loading-files-and-displaying-necessary-features-as-per-files-loaded